# Override utf8_enforcer_tag using Rails custom form builder?

Tags: utf, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to stop `form_for` with `method: get` from passing the `utf8=✓` URL parameter.

If I wanted to do it globally, this would work:

```
# config/initializers/utf8_enforcer_tag.rb
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormTagHelper
      def utf8_enforcer_tag
        ""
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I only want to change the behavior in certain cases. So I want to use a custom form builder. What code should I use, below, to disable the UTF-8 tag?

```
# app/form_builders/no_utf8_form_builder.rb
class NoUtf8FormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  # ???
end
```

Note: here is the [Rails source code for `utf8_enforcer_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L719).

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the implementation of `bring_back_snowman`: https://github.com/steveklabnik/bring_back_snowman

Specifically, https://github.com/steveklabnik/bring_back_snowman/blob/master/lib/bring_back_snowman.rb#L15-L28

Comment: I see that `bring_back_snowman` adjusts `utf8_enforcer_tag` for the whole app. I'd like to make `utf8_enforcer_tag` vary based on which form builder is being used (no change if the default is used). So, I need to find a way for `utf8_enforcer_tag` to look into the form context somehow.